# Customize Eclipse editor to add new features specific to a proprietary language

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-rcp, eclipselink, customization, jface

I'm working on Eclipse IDE from past a year, specifically my development includes JFace technology. Now I want a starting point from where I can add new features to Eclipse editor.

For example we have a proprietary language specific to the company I work for, this language is similar to SQL and is just a layer on top of SQL. What I would like to do is add a functionality similar to CTRL+SPACE or ALT+SHIFT+T or R which brings up a list of suggestions for the method names, variables on JAVA editors etc.. I would like to add this similar feature to our proprietary language on Eclipse editor as well where pressing CTRL+SPACE brings up AUTO ASSIST.

I need a starting point on how to really kick off with implementing such features in Eclipse editor?

Can someone guide me in the path? Probably some good website links which provides me a starting point in implementing such customized projects?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Start with the Eclipse FAQs:

- [FAQ How do I add Content Assist to my language editor?](https://wiki.eclipse.org/FAQ_How_do_I_add_Content_Assist_to_my_language_editor%3F)
- [FAQ How do I add Content Assist to my editor?](https://wiki.eclipse.org/FAQ_How_do_I_add_Content_Assist_to_my_editor%3F)

Also, look at existing source code, for things like JDT: See its [git repo](https://git.eclipse.org/c/jdt/eclipse.jdt.ui.git/).

Comment: Thanks so much for the links, this would really help me in the process.

Comment: In the help link provided I'm unable to figure out a few points - I'm trying to develop a content assist for a new language so how do I define this in the code?, If there a few dependencies that do not show up while trying to add them in Manifest.mf then how do I get them added? Is there a tutorial which guides us through developing content assist for a new language?

Comment: @user3354299 What it sounds like you are asking for is getting started with eclipse dev type tutorial, I recommend http://vogella.com tutorials. If you have a question, ask it as a new question on SO.